# Comparison of C# Linq syntax -vs- VB Linq syntax

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I am trying to  move some of my C# code into VB. When I run the C# code thru Telerik's translator it spits out the VB code below. The VB code will not compile and gives and error on the "a.Remove()" section. The error is

> "Expression does not produce a value"

What would the correct code be to remove the "script" and "a" tags so the VB code works the same as the C# code?

My original C# code:

```
 public static HtmlDocument RemoveUselessTags(HtmlDocument doc)
    {
        doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
            .Where(a => a.Name == "script" || a.Name == "a")
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(a => a.Remove());
        return doc;
    }
```

My "translated" VB code:

```
  Public Shared Function RemoveUselessTags(doc As HtmlDocument) As HtmlDocument
        doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
           .Where(Function(a) a.Name = "script" OrElse a.Name = "a")
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(Function(a) a.Remove())
        Return doc
    End Function
```

Comment: Just use a real `foreach` loop in the first place (in both languages).  It improves the readability of the code, removes unnecessary complications in the syntax (such as the particular one that happened to trip you up) and improves the performance (the memory footprint goes from O(n) to O(1) by not entirely needlessly creating a list that you never use and storing all of the items in it).

Comment: You translation of code is perfect except 'OrElse" should be 'Or'.

Comment: @jdweng - No, `OrElse` is the VB equivalent of the short-circuiting `||` operator in C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `Function`, which is for things which return a value. You should be able to use:

```
ForEach(Sub(a) a.Remove())
```